# Streamline building R Windows Binaries for multiple R versions

Tags: r, r-package

I am developing R packages for an internal use applications at work. Unfortunately, not everybody is on the same version of R. I want to build Windows binaries of my package to support multiple versions, for example, 3.6.x and 4.0.x R.

I can easily do this by building the package (I use `devtools::build(binary = TRUE)`), and then change the R version in RStudio, restart, and run again. But this gets very tedious.

Is there a way to streamline this (e.g., my own custom function to build both at once)? I imagine some CI/CD thing is probably best, but this solution would have to be limited to what I can run locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it in RStudio, write a script to do it.  It would have commands like these:

```
/path/to/R3.6.3/R CMD INSTALL --build /path/to/yourpackage
mv yourpackage.*.zip /path/for/R3.6users
/path/to/R4.0.3/R CMD INSTALL --build /path/to/yourpackage
mv yourpackage.*.zip /path/for/R4.0users
```

You don't need a lot of builds; only the first two parts of the version number (e.g. 3.6 or 4.0) need to match the target system.

You could implement this script in R using `system()` calls, but it's probably simpler to do it using one of the Windows script languages (`.bat` or `.cmd` or whatever).

Comment: Yeah, I suspected this was the route to go. Figuring out my details, but this gets me mostly what I want. Thanks!